# Can't delete file from the git repository?

Tags: git, github, delete-file

I have added file >100 Mb to my git repository and it worked in local git. Unfortunately, github has 100 Mb limitation.

So, I rewrote code so that it doesn't need this big file, then removed it, then commited.

Unfortunately, I still can't push to gothub, because file is still in the repository.

I tried to run

```
git rm --cached my_file.dat

git rm --cached -r my_file.dat

git rm --cached mypath/my_file.dat
```

and all commands failed with

```
fatal: pathspec ... did not match any files
```

How to remove file w/o specifying exact path to it?

**UPDATE**

I tried to run

```
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M
```

and it failed with message

```
Scanning packfile for large blobs completed in 2 ms.
Warning : no large blobs matching criteria found in packfiles - does the repo need to be packed?
```

but still unable to

```
git push origin master
```

with

```
File my_path/my_file.dat is 257.62 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Comment: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: Can you create a new branch, pull the latest and remove it from your local then puush to master?

Comment: Or with a bit more context: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Comment: To my surprise, gothub actually exists! http://gothub.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow remove this file from all commits.

Several ways to do this are :

- if you have a reasonably low number of commits to edit :
  use `git rebase -i` to manually edit commits
- if you have to do it on a large scale (many commits, several branches) :
  use `git filter-branch --index-filter`
  or the `bfg-repo-cleaner` suggested by @Sirko

---

How to use git rebase -i :

if your history looks like this :

```
      big file added here
        v
--*--A--B--C--D--E--F <- master
```

to rework the content of B, you will need to rebase from its parent :

```
git rebase -i A
```

This will open a text editor, which will ask what action you want to take on each single commit from `B` to `F`

It will start with :

```
 pick  B   message
 pick  C   message
 pick  D   message
 ...
```

You want to change `B`, to remove the big file from this commit

```
# set the action on b to 'edit' (or e) :
e B  message
pick  C   message
pick  D   message
...
```

save and close.

Now git will apply the actions you told him to :

- he will rewind your repo up to `A`
- you told git to edit `B` : he will apply `B`, and then stop so that you can do whatever you want
- to remove the big file from this commit :

  ```
  git rm --cached big/file
  git commit --amend
  ```
- now you want to tell git to resume with the rebasing :

  ```
  git rebase --continue
  ```
- you should see messages indicating that git is replaying C then D .. up to F

Comment: `git rebase -i` opens text editor with `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` file opened

Comment: I shows 2 commints (why 2? I have dozens) with `pick` word in the beginning of each line; if I replace one `pick` with `drop` and save the file, it shows `could not apply ..., when you have resolved this problem`

Comment: Did you add the big file on one specific commit ?

Comment: I have few commits but filter-branch is still a straightforward solution: git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f <file>' HEAD as recommended here https://buildvirtual.net/how-to-remove-or-delete-a-file-from-git/

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, removing the file outright is the simplest option (though as you see, it's not entirely simple), provided you don't need the file in your repo.  Another option is to use a tool like `git lfs` to allow your repo to refer to the file without putting the file directly in your repo.  This solves many problems associated with large files in `git` and should be considered if you really do need the file; but rewriting a repo to use `lfs` for a file that's already been committed is another whole topic altogether...

So, back to the issue of removal.  To provide a little more context:

In git there are three places a file might be found.

1) *Work trees* - just the plain files you work on.  `git` makes no special effort to preserve the data here, and it only exists locally. You can remove files from here by means outside `git`, or by using `git rm` (especially if you also need to remove them from the index).

2) *The index* - This is where files are "staged" to make new commits.  When you say `git add` you update the index.  `git` will hang onto data here independent of working copies, but still it's only local and no special effort is made to preserve history.  `git rm` will take a file out of the index.

3) *The database* - This is where your project history exists.  When you say `git commit` you add "objects" that represent your project to the database.  The database is where `git` preserves history and you have to go out of your way to make `git` lose any data from here.  The database is basically what's shared between repos during `push` and `fetch` operations.  `git rm` has no effect on the database.

Now as others have noted, because you have created a commit that includes the file, you need to do more than `git rm`.  The first step is to rewrite the history(ies) of any ref(s) that contain commits that include the file.

Someone said you need to address the commit that "introduced" the file; that's misleading.  You need to dispose of *all* references to the file (or, technically, to the `BLOB` object that represents the file).

Because `rebase` interprets commits in terms of their change relative to their parent, it can handle this in a relatively convenient way, *if* there's not a lot of branching and merging going on after the file was added.  If, for example, the file was created in commit `A`, and the only ref from which `A` is reachable is `master`, and there are no merge commits that are newer than `A` in `master`, then `rebase` is the simplest solution.  Assuming `A` is not the root commit,

```
git rebase -i A^ master
```

(where `A^` is the SHA of the commit that introduced the file); but if `A` is the root commit, meaning `A^` isn't valid, then

```
git rebase -i --root master
```

In the TODO list that pops up, you change the command for `A` to edit, and when given the prompt to edit the commit you remove the file and then tell `rebase` to continue.

At this point it's possible that `git push` will work, because `git` doesn't have to send the whole database; it just sends the history of the ref you tell it to push.  But don't be confused: you *still* haven't removed the file from your database locally.  To do that, you have to ensure nothing (even the reflog) can reach the file and then use `git gc`.  If you've successfully removed the file from all refs' histories, this will happen eventually; which is probably file, unless you're limited on local storage.

There are several important assumptions in the above procedure, and if you just recently committed the file those assumptions may hold.  But if multiple branches exist that can reach commit `A`, and/or if there are merge commits from which you can reach `A`, then doing a `rebase` can become much harder.  That's when you'd look at `git filter-branch` or the `BFG Repo Cleaner` as solutions.  Of the two, `BFG` is far simpler and faster for this task; if you search for it, you can find many sources (including some SO entries) that outline its usage.  Because `filter-branch` is more general-purpose it's harder to use correctly, but then again it's "built in" - no need to download additional software.

All of these techniques rewrite history.  Since you can't push your existing history, that's probably not a big deal (assuming you don't have a second remote to which you've already pushed the changes).

Answer (score 0):

The file is still in the repository's history... You need to remove the commit(s) that introduced it...

If you can cleanly identify the commit that introduced it, then try the following:

```sh
git rebase -i ${COMMIT_ID}^
```

This will present you with a list of commits, where you can choose to `edit` or `drop` certain items. Either mark the offending commit by replacing the default `pick` with `drop` to simply drop it (**and all other changes that the commit makes!**), or mark the offending commit with `edit`, remove the file, re-commit and contiue.

Once you have done this, try pushing again.

---

Git isn't really designed for large binary files, so avoid checking them in.
If you "*need*" to, then it might be worth checking out the [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) project.

Comment: What is `${COMMIT_ID}^`?

Comment: When you do `git log`, you'll see the commit IDs listed along with the commit message and other information. You should replace `${COMMIT_ID}` with this identifier, and then follow that with a hat (`^`), which indicates "_the parent of_". For example `git rebase -i f928b95^`.